# How to put copy a script to the leader node of cluster in AWS cloud to run?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am a newbie in Toil and AWS trying to run HelloWorld.py example in the Toil Document. I have already successfully installed toil and related python packages on my local mac laptop and have setup my account at AWS.
I am at the point where I have created a small leader/worker cluster and stated it:
$ cgcloud create-cluster toil -s 2 -t m3.large
    $ cgcloud ssh toil-leader
Here, the toil document read:
Place the HelloWorld.py script on the leader node, and run:
python HelloWorld.py  --batchSystem=mesos  --mesosMaster=master-private-ip:5050  aws:us-west-2:my-aws-jobstore

My question is: How do I place (copy to) the HelloWorld.py script on the leader node?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `toil rsync-cluster` command. This works as a wrapper to the standard unix command `rsync` and copies the file you specify to the leader node.

It looks like you named your cluster `toil` from your `create-cluster` command above. To copy the file to the cluster's leader you would run

```
$ toil rsync-cluster toil /path/to/HelloWorld.py :/remote/destination
```

This is from the [Toil documentation](http://file:///Users/jesse/Documents/genomics/toil/docs/_build/html/cli.html#rsync-cluster)

> The most frequent use case for the rsync-cluster utility is deploying your Toil script to the Toil leader. Note that the syntax is
>   the same as traditional rsync with the exception of the hostname
>   before the colon. This is not needed in toil rsync-cluster since the
>   hostname is automatically determined by Toil.
>
> Here is an example of its usage:
>
> ```
> $ toil rsync-cluster CLUSTER-NAME-HERE \    
>        ~/localFile :/remoteDestination
> ```